# Maximo IBM rest API not working

Tags: api, rest, maximo

Paging in rest API is not working

/maxrest/rest/mbo/ticket?_maxitems=20&_rsstart=31

Modifying value of rsstart is giving same result

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still having this issue but I'll post an answer anyway for people looking in the future.

The naming of the parameters is "supposed to be" case sensitive. That being said I've run into Maximo instances where it seems to not matter, and other instances where it will only work with proper syntax.

I presume that you are building your own paging logic since I don't believe it is not natively supported by the REST API.

The url you should be using is:

```
/maxrest/rest/mbo/ticket?_maxItems=20&_rsStart=31
```